# Conversion of a small int type field to a string not working

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a model and method below. The field type of BudgetHealth in the database is smallint/null.
I want to convert the value retrieved to a string. Code compiles but fails during runtime with an error
that I cannot do the conversion.

What is the best way to write this?

```
        public string ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string BudgetHealth { get; set; }
        public string TeamHealth { get; set; }

        public Projecthealthnotes GetProgressHealthDetails(string projectId, DateTime strstatusDate)
            {

                Projecthealthnotes objProjHnotes = new Projecthealthnotes();

                objProjHnotes = (from jj in _objContext.tbl_Project_Status_Followup
                                 where (jj.ProjectID.Equals(projectId)) && (jj.StatusDate.Equals(strstatusDate))

                                 select new Projecthealthnotes()
                                 {
                                     ProjectId = jj.ProjectID,
                                     BudgetHealth = Convert.ToString(jj.BudgetHealth),
                                     TeamHealth = jj.TeamHealth                                 
                                 }).FirstOrDefault();

                return objProjHnotes;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
BudgetHealth = ((jj.BudgetHealth != null) ? jj.BudgetHealth.ToString() : String.Empty),
```

Edit: It's actually probably this line, rather than your BudgetHealth:

```
jj.StatusDate.Equals(strstatusDate)
```

Because strstatusDate is a DateTime

Comment: Thanks. It does not work. It won't allow me to do the conversion to string.

Comment: No thanks. There is nothing wrong with that. The problem is conversion to string with Budgethealth.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use let keyword in query expression for cast int to the string value.

[let](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) : In a query expression, it is sometimes useful to store the result of a sub-expression in order to use it in subsequent clauses. You can do this with the let keyword, which creates a new range variable and initializes it with the result of the expression you supply. Once initialized with a value, the range variable cannot be used to store another value. However, if the range variable holds a queryable type, it can be queried.

I hope below code will be helpful to you.

```
objProjHnotes = (from jj in _objContext.tbl_Project_Status_Followup
                  let strBudgetHealth = Convert.ToString(jj.BudgetHealth) 
                 where (jj.ProjectID.Equals(projectId)) && (jj.StatusDate.Equals(strstatusDate))

                 select new Projecthealthnotes()
                 {
                     ProjectId = jj.ProjectID,
                     BudgetHealth = strBudgetHealth,
                     TeamHealth = jj.TeamHealth                                 
                 }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks. This does not work. Here is what I got. [System.NotSupportedException] = {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}